Аргументы storybook
У меня есть компонент input:
import clsx from 'clsx'

import styles from './input.module.scss'
import {ChangeEvent, ComponentPropsWithoutRef, ElementRef, forwardRef, useState} from 'react'
import {EyeOutline, EyeOffOutline, SearchOutline} from '@/assets'
import {Typography} from '@/components'

export type InputProps = {
    errorMessage?: string
    label?: string
    variant?: 'text' | 'password' | 'search',
} & ComponentPropsWithoutRef<'input'>

/**
 * Input component with optional search and password toggle functionality.
 *
 * @component
 * @param {Object} props - The component props.
 * @param {string} [props.className] - Additional class name for styling the component.
 * @param {string} [props.errorMessage] - Error message displayed below the input field.
 * @param {string} [props.label] - Label text for the input field.
 * @param {boolean} [props.search] - If true, a search icon is displayed inside the input field.
 * @param {boolean} [props.disabled] - If true, the input field is disabled.
 * @param {string} [props.type] - The type of the input field (e.g., 'text' or 'password').
 * @param {string | number} [props.value] - The current value of the input field.
 * @param {function(ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void} [props.onChange] - Callback function invoked when the input value changes.
 * @param {React.Ref<HTMLInputElement>} ref - Reference to the input element.
 * @returns {JSX.Element} The Input component.
 */

export const Input = forwardRef<ElementRef<'input'>, InputProps>(
    (
        {
            label,
            variant = 'text',
            errorMessage,
            className,
            onChange,
            disabled,
            value,
            type,
            placeholder,
            ...rest
        },
        ref
    ) => {
        const [showPassword, setShowPassword] = useState(false)
        const isPassword = variant === 'password'
        const changedType = type || (isPassword && !showPassword ? 'password' : 'text')
        const isSearch = variant === 'search'

        const classNames = {
            wrapper: styles.wrapper,
            label: clsx(styles.label, disabled && styles.disabledLabel),
            container: styles.container,
            input: clsx(
                styles.input,
                errorMessage && styles.error,
                isSearch && styles.search,
                isPassword && styles.password,
                className
            ),
            eyeBtn: styles.eyeButton,
            search: clsx(
                styles.searchIcon,
                disabled && styles.disabledSearch,
                errorMessage && styles.errorSearch
            ),
        } as const

        const onChangeHandler = (e: ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
            onChange?.(e)
        }

        const showPasswordHandler = () => {
            setShowPassword(prev => !prev)
        }

        return (
            <div className={classNames.wrapper}>
                {label && (
                    <Typography className={classNames.label} variant="text14">
                        {label}
                    </Typography>
                )}
                <div className={classNames.container}>
                    {isSearch && <SearchOutline height={24} width={24} className={classNames.search}/>}
                    <input
                        className={classNames.input}
                        onChange={onChangeHandler}
                        placeholder={placeholder}
                        type={changedType}
                        value={value}
                        disabled={disabled}
                        ref={ref}
                        {...rest}
                    />
                    {isPassword && (
                        <button
                            className={classNames.eyeBtn}
                            disabled={disabled}
                            onClick={showPasswordHandler}
                            type={'button'}
                        >
                            {showPassword ? (
                                <EyeOffOutline height={24} width={24}/>
                            ) : (
                                <EyeOutline height={24} width={24}/>
                            )}
                        </button>
                    )}
                </div>
                {errorMessage && (
                    <Typography variant="text14" color={'var(--danger-500)'}>
                        {errorMessage}
                    </Typography>
                )}
            </div>
        )
    }
)


вот его история для сторибука:
import type { Meta, StoryObj } from '@storybook/react'

import { Input } from './input'
import { useState } from 'react'

const meta = {
  component: Input,
  tags: ['autodocs'],
  argTypes: {
    type: {
      control: { type: 'select' },
      options: ['password', 'text'],
    },
  },
  args: {
    disabled: false,
    label: 'Label',
    value: 'inctagram@gmail.com',
  },
  title: 'Components/Input',
} satisfies Meta<typeof Input>

export default meta
type Story = StoryObj<typeof meta>

export const Default: Story = {
  args: {},
}

export const Disabled: Story = {
  args: {
    disabled: true,
  },
}

export const Password: Story = {
  args: {
  },

  render: args => {
    const { disabled, errorMessage } = args
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')
    const [type, setType] = useState<'text' | 'password'>('password')

    const togglePasswordVisibility = () => {
      setType(prevType => (prevType === 'password' ? 'text' : 'password'))
    }

    return (
        <Input
            placeholder={'Password'}
            variant={'password'}
            disabled={disabled}
            errorMessage={errorMessage}
            value={value}
            type={type}
            onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
            onClick={togglePasswordVisibility} // Ensure this event handler is not conflicting with button click.
        />
    )
  },
}

export const Search: Story = {
  args: {},

  render: args => {
    const { disabled, errorMessage } = args
    const [value, setValue] = useState('')

    return (
      <Input
        variant={'search'}
        disabled={disabled}
        errorMessage={errorMessage}
        value={value}
        onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)}
      />
    )
  },
}

export const InputWithError: Story = {
  args: {
    errorMessage: 'Error',
  },
}

Как в сторибуке при варианте инпута password менять менять и аргумент type который есть в интерфейсе storybook:
 argTypes: {
    type: {
      control: { type: 'select' },
      options: ['password', 'text'],
    },
  },

Интерфейс сторибука где type должен меняться когда нажимаем на иконку
